# Where is Zend_Reflection_Property's isPublic() and other methods like it documented and defined?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Dear Zend Framework expert,

I'm trying to understand how the Zend Framework API documentation is organized. For example, look at this code snippet:

```
$reflectionClass = new Zend_Reflection_Class($object);
$properties = $reflectionClass->getProperties();
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    if ($property->isPublic()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

While typing this code in Eclipse/PDT, I notice that Eclipse didn't give me code completion hints for what methods were available to call on the $property object. I expected it to list methods like isPublic(), isStatic(), ...etc.

So I go to the [v1.11 Zend Framework API documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/) and here's what it says: Zend_Reflection_Class's getProperties() returns an array of Zend_Reflection_Property objects, which makes $property (in the code above) a Zend_Reflection_Property. I check the API documentation for Zend_Reflection_Property but it has no isPublic() method. In fact, only 2 methods are listed for Zend_Reflection_Property: getDeclaringClass() and getDocComment(). The documentation doesn't even tell you if Zend_Reflection_Property extends another class from which it might inherit methods like isPublic().

Next I go to the actual code for Zend_Reflection_Property. In the code, I find that Zend_Reflection_Property extends ReflectionProperty, so I assume that isPublic() is inherited from ReflectionProperty. But I could not find documentation for the ReflectionProperty class to verify this. And worse, I couldn't even find the code that defines the ReflectionProperty class by doing a recursive grep in the Zend directory!

My question is this: How does one go about finding all the methods (including inherited ones) available to call on a ZF object in general, and in, say, a Zend_Reflection_Property object in particular (as in this case)?

This is the kind of question you want to be able to answer by reading the API documentation, right? Ideally, you shouldn't have to go into library code to figure out how to use its classes. But I'm even willing to read code- where is the code for the ReflectionProperty class that Zend_Reflection_Property extends?

Maybe I just don't know my way around the Zend Framework API documentation. I would greatly appreciate being enlightened by a Zend Framework expert.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReflectionProperty` is a built-in [PHP's Reflection API](http://php.net/Reflection) class. The code is not available as PHP code, because it is compiled within PHP.

You can easily find the documentation for with by looking at http://php.net/ReflectionProperty. The auto-generated documentation (phpDocumentor documentation) that Zend provides is usually the best docs you can have for an API, and Zend is no exception.

The reason why Eclipse will not auto-complete on the `$property` object is because `getProperties` returns an array. In PHP, arrays can contain various objects of differents types:

```
$arr = array(new stdClass, new ReflectionProperty);
```

...making it impossible for Eclipse to find out what type is the object/variable you are accessing, especially in a loop. The only way for Eclipse to figure that out would be to execute the code at each keystroke, and that would be very impractical.

Comment: Thank you, netcoder! (Oops, didn't know about accepting. Sorry.)